# how do i connect my localhost app to mongodb in js

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, express, server

i'm doing a cours on data base. We deployed a localhost server on port 3000 that serves an app.js. we the created a cluster on mongodb, created a user with password that write and read and allowed access from any ip ( 0.0.0.0/0  (includes your current IP address)).

in the exercice i have to connect the app to this cluster using the line :

```
mongodb+srv://redhewlett:<password>@cluster0.fzi4c.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

i replaced the password with the right one, then in the exercice they say we also have to replace SRV with our server. when i put http://localhost:3000 it says the connection failed.
this is the server's code:

```
const http = require("http");
const app = require("./app");

const normalizePort = (val) => {
  const port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    return val;
  }
  if (port >= 0) {
    return port;
  }
  return false;
};
const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || "3000");
app.set("port", port);

const errorHandler = (error) => {
  if (error.syscall !== "listen") {
    throw error;
  }
  const address = server.address();
  const bind = typeof address === "string" ? "pipe " + address : "port: " + port;
  switch (error.code) {
    case "EACCES":
      console.error(bind + " requires elevated privileges.");
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case "EADDRINUSE":
      console.error(bind + " is already in use.");
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
};

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.on("error", errorHandler);
server.on("listening", () => {
  const address = server.address();
  const bind = typeof address === "string" ? "pipe " + address : "port " + port;
  console.log("Listening on " + bind);
});

server.listen(port);
```

and the app's code:

```
const express = require("express");
//mongoose import to work with the data base
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
//call express methode to creat the app
const app = express();
mongoose
  .connect("mongodb+srv://redhewlett:<password>@cluster0.fzi4c.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("Connexion to MongoDB successfull !"))
  .catch(() => console.log("Connexion to MongoDB failed !"));

//intercept any request containing json() content and put it in the request body (same as body parser)
app.use(express.json());
//header on response object
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS");
  next();
});
//middleware receive request and respond then they allow other codes to run to do things with the request
//handle post request
app.post("/api/stuff", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  //status 201 tells that we creat a ressource
  res.status(201).json({ message: "new object created" });
  next();
});
//handle get request
app.get("/api/stuff", (req, res, next) => {
  const stuff = [
    {
      _id: "oeihfzeoi",
      title: "Mon premier objet",
      description: "Les infos de mon premier objet",
      imageUrl: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/06/11/18/56/camera-4267692_1280.jpg",
      price: 4900,
      userId: "qsomihvqios",
    },
    {
      _id: "oeihfzeomoihi",
      title: "Mon deuxième objet",
      description: "Les infos de mon deuxième objet",
      imageUrl: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/06/11/18/56/camera-4267692_1280.jpg",
      price: 2900,
      userId: "qsomihvqios",
    },
  ];
  res.status(200).json(stuff);
});
//export the app so we can use it in our server
module.exports = app;
```

i let the srv and password as is so you can see where they go.
the cours is kinda outdate, the mongodb interface changed. in the cours they don't show how they replaced with the server so i don't understand how to write it.

Comment: `http://localhost:3000 it says the connection failed` that's probably because MongoDB runs on port 27017 by default, so it should be `localhost:27017`. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/

Comment: so i should do mongodb+http://localhost:27017://redhewlett:<password>@cluster0.fzi4c.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority    ?

Comment: Ha, no, I misunderstood. You don't have MongoDB running locally, right? You are running a local Node server on port 3000, but you want to connect to a remote MongoDB instance? In that case I don't know, I'm not sure what `they say we also have to replace SRV with our server` means. Normally, you connect to Mongo with the URL they give you, that's all.

Comment: yes my serv is localhost on 3000, yes it's weird i don't get it, thks tho'